# Android Studio 1.4 it's possible to get old template for new project?

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently updated my Android Studio to version 1.4 and I noticed that every new project looks completely different. It has material design by default and CustomLayout instead of Relative. The problem is that I'm currently learning android development and I need old "template" for every new project to matching code in my book. My question is: It's possible to get old template for new projects in Android Studio 1.4?

Comment: You can download the old version of Android Studio from http://tools.android.com/download/studio/stable

Comment: Customize one project to your needs and make copies of it every time you need to start from scratch.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I think it's very bad idea because in this case application name and package signature will be the same for all apps.

Comment: @KrupalShah Thanks for idea! If there is no other solutions - I downgrade my IDE to 1.3.1.

Comment: And you can customize them both in build.gradle. First thing you can do after you "clone" your new project.

Answer (score 0):

For every new layout there is a corresponding `content_xxx` layout included in that new layout. You are supposed to modify that one.

Comment: I understand that new approach may be better. But in my case i need similar code for better learning experience.

Comment: They are not going to change it back anyway